# IAudioEndpointVolume.SetMode() fails with "A call to an OS function failed"

Tags: delphi, winapi

I am trying to write a code that mutes all audio interfaces (I have 2). The interface `IAudioEndpointVolume` seems to be the correct solution.

My current code looks like this:

```
unit AudioVolCntrl;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils;

procedure MuteAllAudioDevices(bMute: boolean);

implementation

uses
  ActiveX, ComObj;

const
  CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator : TGUID = '{BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E}';
  IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator : TGUID = '{A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6}';
  IID_IMMDevice : TGUID = '{D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F}';
  IID_IMMDeviceCollection : TGUID = '{0BD7A1BE-7A1A-44DB-8397-CC5392387B5E}';
  IID_IAudioEndpointVolume : TGUID = '{5CDF2C82-841E-4546-9722-0CF74078229A}';
  IID_IAudioMeterInformation : TGUID = '{C02216F6-8C67-4B5B-9D00-D008E73E0064}';
  IID_IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback : TGUID = '{657804FA-D6AD-4496-8A60-352752AF4F89}';
  IID_IMMNotificationClient : TGUID = '{7991EEC9-7E89-4D85-8390-6C703CEC60C0}';

  DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE = $00000001;
  DEVICE_STATE_UNPLUGGED = $00000002;
  DEVICE_STATE_NOTPRESENT = $00000004;
  DEVICE_STATEMASK_ALL = $00000007;

type
  EDataFlow = TOleEnum;

const
  eRender = $00000000;
  eCapture = $00000001;
  eAll = $00000002;
  EDataFlow_enum_count = $00000003;

type
  ERole = TOleEnum;

const
  eConsole = $00000000;
  eMultimedia = $00000001;
  eCommunications = $00000002;
  ERole_enum_count = $00000003;

type
  IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{657804FA-D6AD-4496-8A60-352752AF4F89}']
  end;

  IAudioEndpointVolume = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{5CDF2C82-841E-4546-9722-0CF74078229A}']
    function RegisterControlChangeNotify(AudioEndPtVol: IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function UnregisterControlChangeNotify(AudioEndPtVol: IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetChannelCount(out PInteger): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetMasterVolumeLevel(fLevelDB: single; pguidEventContext: PGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(fLevelDB: single; pguidEventContext: PGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMasterVolumeLevel(out fLevelDB: single): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMasterVolumeLevelScaler(out fLevelDB: single): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetChannelVolumeLevel(nChannel: Integer; fLevelDB: Single; pguidEventContext: PGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(nChannel: Integer; fLevelDB: Single; pguidEventContext: PGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetChannelVolumeLevel(nChannel: Integer; out fLevelDB: Single): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(nChannel: Integer; out fLevel: Single): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetMute(bMute: BOOL(*!*); pguidEventContext: PGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMute(out bMute: BOOL(*!*)): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetVolumeStepInfo(pnStep: Integer; out pnStepCount: Integer): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function VolumeStepUp(pguidEventContext: PGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function VolumeStepDown(pguidEventContext: PGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function QueryHardwareSupport(out pdwHardwareSupportMask): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetVolumeRange(out pflVolumeMindB: Single; out pflVolumeMaxdB: Single; out pflVolumeIncrementdB: Single): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  IAudioMeterInformation = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{C02216F6-8C67-4B5B-9D00-D008E73E0064}']
    function GetPeakValue(out Peak: Real): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  IPropertyStore = interface(IUnknown)
  end;

  IMMDevice = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F}']
    function Activate(const refId: TGUID; dwClsCtx: DWORD; pActivationParams: PInteger; out pEndpointVolume: IAudioEndpointVolume): HRESULT; stdCall;
    function OpenPropertyStore(stgmAccess: DWORD; out ppProperties: IPropertyStore): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetId(out ppstrId: PLPWSTR): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetState(out State: Integer): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  IMMDeviceCollection = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{0BD7A1BE-7A1A-44DB-8397-CC5392387B5E}']
    function GetCount(out pcDevices: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Item(nDevice: UINT; out ppDevice: IMMDevice): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  IMMNotificationClient = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{7991EEC9-7E89-4D85-8390-6C703CEC60C0}']
  end;

  IMMDeviceEnumerator = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6}']
    function EnumAudioEndpoints(dataFlow: EDataFlow; deviceState: SYSUINT; out DevCollection: IMMDeviceCollection): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDF: SYSUINT; ER: SYSUINT; out Dev: IMMDevice): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDevice(pwstrId: pointer; out Dev: IMMDevice): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback(pClient: IMMNotificationClient): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function UnregisterEndpointNotificationCallback(pClient: IMMNotificationClient): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

// TODO: Something is fishy.
// In Delphi 2006: SetMute() does only work if this argument is BOOL, and if the interface is Boolean (but the interface should be BOOL!)
// In Delphi 10, it does not work at all.
procedure MuteAllAudioDevices(bMute: boolean(*!*));
var
  MMDeviceCollection: IMMDeviceCollection;
  MMDeviceEnumerator: IMMDeviceEnumerator;
  nDevCount: UINT;
  dev: IMMdevice;
  pEndpointVolume: IAudioEndpointVolume;
  iDev: Integer;
begin
  if not Succeeded(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, nil, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator, MMDeviceEnumerator)) then RaiseLastOSError;

  MMDeviceCollection := nil;
  if not Succeeded(MMDeviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(eRender, DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE, MMDeviceCollection)) then RaiseLastOSError;

  if not Succeeded(MMDeviceCollection.GetCount(nDevCount)) then RaiseLastOSError;

  for iDev := 0 to nDevCount - 1 do
  begin
    if not Succeeded(MMDeviceCollection.item(iDev, dev)) then RaiseLastOSError;
    if not Succeeded(Dev.Activate(IID_IAudioEndpointVolume, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, nil, pEndpointVolume)) then RaiseLastOSError;
    if not Succeeded(pEndpointVolume.SetMute(bMute, nil)) then RaiseLastOSError;
  end;
end;

initialization
  CoInitialize(nil);
finalization
  CoUninitialize;
end.
```

The problem is that the code `pEndpointVolume.SetMute(bMute, nil)` is very unstable. Something's not correct.

The first interface is muted correctly. The second interface fails with "A call to an OS function failed" if I compile with Delphi 10. In Delphi 2006, it works only if the interface arguments has data type `Boolean` (which is wrong) and the function argument `BOOL` (see also my source code comment). I think something with the arguments or the usage is not correct, therefore the behavior seems to be undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the method call in a debugger?

Comment: @Anders I can only tell that the error happens inside `SetMute`, but I don't have the source. I think Windows implements this method.

Comment: You can step into it with a debugger even if you don't have the source. We don't care about what happens inside the function, first we need to know what the stack looks like when you are about to call the function. At the assembly level, when you are about to execute the call instruction for SetMute then you should look at the stack (ESP), it should have the value of pEndpointVolume and the two parameters (3 32-bit numbers) (assuming 32-bit x86). In WinDbg you would just do "dd ESP" and it will dump the stack as DWORDs...

Comment: @DanielMarschall You can't use `GetLastError()` (and by extension, the parameterless version of `RaiseLastOSError()`) with COM interface calls. They don't use `SetLastError()` to report errors, they return `HRESULT` error codes directly, which your code is using `Succeeded()` to handle.

Comment: @DanielMarschall If you want to raise an exception when a COM interface call fails, use [`OleCheck()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.ComObj.OleCheck) instead, eg: `OleCheck(MMDeviceCollection.item(iDev, dev)); OleCheck(Dev.Activate(IID_IAudioEndpointVolume, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, nil, pEndpointVolume)); OleCheck(pEndpointVolume.SetMute(bMute, nil));`

Comment: Thank you for the hints! I have now found out that the actual error is `E_INVALIDARG`. I have looked at the CPU debugger to find out which values are put into the stack. `SetMute` works if the 2nd argument is `$00000001` . It will fail if it is `$FFFFFFFF` . The weird things: (1) both values should be OK since (LongBool) `TRUE` is defined as <> 0.  And (2) If I write `BOOL(1)`, Delphi converts it to `$FFFFFFFF` . I have no idea why.

Comment: `LongBool` is indeed set to -1 when assigned a `Boolean` true, not 1 (probably stems from `BOOL` not being an OLE type, `VARIANT_BOOL` is, and `VARIANT_TRUE` is -1). `SetMute()` is documented to accept 0 or 1 only, hence the error on -1. `BOOL` is an `int`, so try using `Integer` instead of `BOOL` in the `SetMute()` declaration, then type-cast your `Boolean` values to `Integer` to get the proper values. If you want the parameter to be `BOOL`, you can use a `PInteger` typecast to get the correct value, eg: `var bTmpMute: BOOL; PInteger(@bTmpMute)^ := Integer(bMute); SetMute(bTmpMute, nil);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It works now. Can you please send your replies as answer?
In my case, I defined the type `type BOOL_ = DWORD`. The cast `boolean` to `BOOL_` works as expected.

Comment: Though I understand what happened, I am still a bit confused. The Windows interface states that it is a `BOOL`, and the value `TRUE` and `FALSE` are expected. In the original C++ headers, `TRUE` is defined as 1. So far, so good. Delphi supports the type `Windows.BOOL = Longbool`, but its definition of true is -1. So, does that mean that I cannot trust Delphi's `BOOL` anymore, and do I need to expect that other WinAPI calls with BOOLs will also fail if I don't do this workaround?